# Help implementing Least Squares algorithm in C [was: want to find the square root of an array]

Tags: c, algorithm

the formula is pretty complicated. the numerator is num and the denominator is den, in the formula there is a root on the denominator so i have putted den in sqrrt() but sqrrt only accepts doubles

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#define LEN 11
// for the following set of x and y find r by the formula ..
float sum(float arr[]);
void main(void)
{    int i;
    float x[]={43.22,39.87,41.85,43.23,40.06,53.29,53.29,54.14,49.12,40.71,55.15};
    float y[]={102.43,100.93,97.43,97.81,98.32,98.32,100.07,97.08,91.59,94.85,94.6};
    float num,den[LEN],r[LEN],xy[LEN],x2[LEN],y2[LEN];
    for(i=0;i<LEN;i++)
    {
        x2[i]=x[i]*x[i];
        y2[i]=y[i]*y[i];
        xy[i]=x[i]*y[i];
    }
    num=sum(xy)-sum(x)*sum(y);
    for(i=0;i<LEN;i++)
    {
        den[i]=((LEN*sum(x2)-(sum(x))*(sum(x)))*(LEN*sum(y2))-(sum(y2))*(sum(y2)));
        r[i]=num /sqrt(den);  /*<----------the problem is here-----> */

    }
    printf("%f",r);
    getch();
}
float sum(float arr[])
    {
    int i;
    float total=0;
    for(i=0;i<=LEN;i++)
    {
        total+=arr[i];
    }
    return total;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "square root of an array".

Comment: also, explain your code a bit; which formula are you using (cited in the comment)

Comment: Perhaps there's a problem with the upcast/downcast? I think sqrt() takes/returns a double. Having said that, this whole snippet is very unclear with its purpose.

Comment: And the problem is...? (Please state your question in the form of a question.)

Comment: **Aside:** A square matrix (often represented by a 2D array) may be multiplied by it's dual (transpose in the simplest case) to produce a matrix of the same size. That allows us to have `A = B*B` where A is the square of B, and B therefor the square-root of A. But somehow I don't think that this is what is being asked here...this looks more like some unspecified bin-by-bin calculation.

Comment: Ahh.  I think he means LEAST SQUARES.  Basically given the set of (x,y) coordinates, the above derives the line of best fit, and r is the residual.

Comment: @Il-Bhima: I think you're probably correct that it is intended to be a least-squares regression of y on x.  The second loop is not going to do its job properly unless there is some reference to `x[i]` and `y[i]`, though.  And I think the residual can be calculated without a second loop.

Comment: @bhima : yeah you got it right.its a program from the book LET US C by yashwant kanetkar

Comment: @fahad but don't make people waste their time to guess what you could have explained clearly!

Comment: good job Bhima! while `square root` and `least squares` both have `square` in it, there's a big difference between the two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of sheer boredom I have fixed your code.  It is still ugly and extremely inefficient but compiles and should work.  I'll leave you or someone else to make it decent.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define LEN 11


// for the following set of x and y find r by the formula ..
float sum(float arr[]);
int main(void)
{ int i;
      float x[]={43.22,39.87,41.85,43.23,40.06,53.29,53.29,54.14,49.12,40.71,55.15};
      float y[]={102.43,100.93,97.43,97.81,98.32,98.32,100.07,97.08,91.59,94.85,94.6};


      float num,den,r[LEN],xy[LEN],x2[LEN],y2[LEN];
      for(i=0;i<LEN;i++)
          {
                x2[i]=x[i]*x[i];
                y2[i]=y[i]*y[i];
                xy[i]=x[i]*y[i];
              }
      num=LEN*sum(xy)-sum(x)*sum(y);
      den = (LEN*sum(x2)) - sum(x)*sum(x);

      float alpha = sum(y)/LEN - (num/den)*sum(x)/LEN;

      printf("beta = %f,  alpha = %f\n", num/den, alpha);     
      for(i=0;i<LEN;i++)
          {
            float term = y[i] - alpha - (num/den)*x[i];
            r[i] = (term*term);

                printf("%f",r[i]);
          }
}
float sum(float arr[])
  {
      int i;
      float total=0;
      for(i=0;i<=LEN;i++)
          {
                total+=arr[i];
              }
      return total;
      }
```

Comment: what are alpha and beta here?
+ why dint u use n in the denominator! the formula has n in the denominator!

Comment: formulae use symbols which have a meaning. Ask yourself: what is the "meaning" of n in the formula? Likely it is just the number of elements; you don't need to use n, if you have already LEN "representing" that value.

Comment: disregard my prev comments if you refer to `den = (LEN*sum(x2)) - sum(x)*sum(x);` - but the comment is ok anyway. Consider also showing us the formula you have!

Comment: the invite to show the formula was for the OP;) so that we can see what he's seeing since it seems in its formula he has n

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the index den[i] at the denominator....instead in your code you have just passed the base address!

```
 r[i]=num /sqrt(den[i]);
```

If this is what you want to achieve, which is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To be consistent with the rest of the code, you should presumably be writing:

```
r[i] = num / sqrt(den[i]);
```

However, the calculation is not one I recognize.  The body of the second loop is going to produce the same result for each value in `den` and therefore also in `r`, which is probably not what the question asked for.

Comment: i guess i am sending the address of the array to the function so i dont need to add [i] to it

Comment: @fahad: the `sqrt()` function only accepts a `double` (or a value such as an integer or `float` that can be converted to `double`); it does not accept pointers.

Comment: why did you repeat gavishna's answer?

Comment: @vol7ron: I didn't; I was typing at the same time that Gavishna was.  I fixed up the typography of Gavishna's answer too...and my answer contains some content which the other does not, which is why I have not removed mine.

Comment: it stinks that I can't see timestamps :)